# When Objects "Hit" Each Other - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, position

How can one keep track of when objects *hit* each other? Below is an example of a *bullet* (`div`) that flies around, hitting a triangle (`svg` `polygon`). How can one know when the bullet is within the green area of the triangle?

```js
var left1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("bullet").style.left);
var left2 = 0; 

setInterval(bounce, 10);
function bounce() {
  if ( left1 < (window.innerWidth - 35) ) {
    left1++; 
    left2 = left1; 
    document.getElementById("bullet").style.left = left1 + "px"; 
    
  }
  if ( left1 >= (window.innerWidth -35) ) {
    left2--;
    document.getElementById("bullet").style.left = left2 + "px"; 
  }
  if ( left2 <= 0 ) {
    left1 = 0;   
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="bullet" style="position:absolute; top:100px; width: 15px; height:15px; background-color: #000;"></div>
  
<svg height="200" width="200" style="position:absolute; top: 0px; left: 100px;">
  <polygon points="100,10 200,200 0,200" style="fill:#23ac6a;"/>  
</svg>
```

Comment: What you want is called collision detection. Many libraries come with this.

Answer (score 1):

The svg `polygon` element provides a property called `points` which returns the values specified in its `points` attribute as an array-like structure called an `SVGPointList`. Each element of the structure has an `x` and `y` property which is relative to the position and `viewBox` of the `svg` element. You can use those values to figure out the x and y coordinates of the bounds of the triangle in relation to your moving `div` and from there detect if any of the `div`'s corners are inside the triangle.

So let's say your `polygon` has an id of `triangle`, you can get an array of those points with `Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById('triangle').points)`